# How to make async operations (GPS + API Call) with Watchkit and

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I am a bit stucked with Watchkit/iOS App communication. This is what I am trying to do

1. Press a button on the watch
2. Get current GPS location (via the phone)
3. Make a backend call with the GPS location
4. Present the backend result on the watch

I guess I am on the right track with **WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication** and **handleWatchKitExtensionRequest** but how can I make async calls?

```
func application(application: UIApplication!,
        handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!,
        reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {

            // 1
            if let request = userInfo["request"] as? String {
                if request == "refreshData" {

                    var backendService = BackendService()
                    var locationManager = LocationManager()
                    locationManager.updateLocation()

                    // How to wait for location manager to get lat/long?

                    backendService.makeAFantasticCAll(locationManager.latitude, longitude: locationManager.longitude)

                    // How to wait for result? Should i use a delegate? How can i fire reply() in this delegate?

                    // 3
                    reply(["result": NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(result)])

                    return
                }
            }

            // 4
            reply([:])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nestedCompletion handler are one solution (but hard to read)

```
func application(application: UIApplication!,
    handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!,
    reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {

    if let request = userInfo["request"] as? String {

        if request == "refreshData" {

            // Get GPS Location
            var locationManager = LocationManager.sharedInstance
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocationWithCompletionHandler { (latitude, longitude, status, verboseMessage, error) -> () in

                // Call backend
                var backendService = BackendService()
                backendService.makeAFantasticCAll(latitude, longitude: longitude) { ( result:Result?, error:String?) -> () in

                    if let title: String = result?.title  {
                        reply(["title": title])
                    }

                }

            }

            return
        }
    }

    reply([:])
```

}